# Writing a tuple search with Django ORM

Tags: python, django, django-queryset

I'm trying to write a search based on tuples with the Django ORM syntax.

The final sql statement should look something like:

```
SELECT * FROM mytable WHERE (field_a,field_b) IN ((1,2),(3,4));
```

I know I can achieve this in django using the extra keyword:

```
MyModel.objects.extra(
    where=["(field_a, field_b) IN %s"],
    params=[((1,2),(3,4))]
)
```

but the "extra" keyword will be deprecated at some point in django so I'd like a pure ORM/django solution.

Searching the web, I found https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/33015 and the comment from Simon Charette, something like the snippet below could be OK, but I can't get it to work.

```
from django.db.models import Func, lookups

class ExpressionTuple(Func):
    template = '(%(expressions)s)'
    arg_joiner = ","


MyModel.objects.filter(lookups.In(
    ExpressionTuple('field_a', 'field_b'),
    ((1,2),(3,4)),
))
```

I'm using Django 3.2 but I don't expect Django 4.x to do a big difference here. My db backend is posgresql in case it matters.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For reference and inspired from akshay-jain proposal, I managed to write something that works:

```
from django.db.models import Func,Value

def ValueTuple(items):
    return tuple(Value(i) for i in items)

class Tuple(Func):
    function = ''

qs = (
    MyModel.objects
    .alias(a=Tuple('field_a', 'field_b'))
    .filter(a__in=ValueTuple([(1, 2), (3, 4)])
)
```

It does produces a sql query like

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE (field_a,field_b) IN ((1,2),(3,4));
```

And can be extended to more fields than just two.

I didn't do any benchmarks to compare it to Q objects filtering though.

Answer (score 4):

I can think of one solution which will build the [query beforehand using `Q`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/topics/db/queries/#complex-lookups-with-q-objects) and then pass it through filter function:

```
q = Q()
for (item1, item2) in [(1,2),(3,4)]:
    q |= Q(field_one=item1, field_two=item2)

Mymodel.objects.filter(q)
```

Another more robust solution would be like this:

```
q = Q()

fields = ['field_one', 'field_two']

for item in [(1,2),(3,4)]:
   q |= Q(**dict(zip(fields, item)))
```

Here I am zipping the fields and item from the list of items, then passing it as an unpacked dictionary to `Q`. Its a similar implementation to previous example but here the number of fields can be many but it won't increase the number of lines in the code.

Comment: Yes it works but it becomes less and less efficient when the number of values in the list [(1,2), (3,4), ...] become large.

Comment: @BobMorane how large are we talking about?

Comment: 1k to 10k roughly

Answer (score 0):

```
from django.db.models import Func, lookups

class Tuple(Func):
    function = '(%s)'

    def as_sql(self, compiler, connection):
        sql, params = super().as_sql(compiler, connection)
        if sql.endswith(',)'):
            sql = sql[:-2] + ')'
        return sql, params

MyModel.objects.filter((Func('field_a', function='(%s)'), Func('field_b', function='(%s)'))__in=[(1,2),(3,4)])
```

With these changes, the resulting SQL query should be something like:

```
SELECT * FROM mytable WHERE (field_a, field_b) IN ((1, 2), (3, 4))
```

Comment: Unfortunately, I got a syntax error: the pattern `(...)__in=...` is not valid